# Wordpress add_action before loading comments

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to write a plugin which should load before loading the comments or after the page content has loaded.
I am trying to use `add_action('pre_get_comments', 'my_function');`,
but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not enough, please add details. And what do you want to do with that ?

Comment: It actually doesn't do any thing. The plugin is simply not called. I removed all the codes and set a simple echo. Even it wasn't called.

Comment: Show us corresponding code. What is your theme ? How do you call comments in your theme ?

Comment: This is what I used to call the function.      add_action('pre_get_comments', 'display_query_div');'                       I have did it through the add_filter(the_content,'display_query_div');. however, I get a bad feeling that it is tabooed.

Comment: Also, no theme. I am trying to make it generic so any one can use the plugin no matter what the theme is. Therefore, manually adding the do_action in side page seems to be a bit ...um..you know.

Comment: Update your question with your code, don't forget `display_query_div` code